# How to remove a newly created user in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, users, user-management

I added a user just for learning purpose how to add user using the command `sudo useradd username`followed by my password, the user is created successfully.

Now I don't want it and running the command `sudo userdel username` in terminal, instead of removing the user it is showing

```
userdel: user sonu is currently used by process 13404.
```

Also I tried to remove it from user & accounts option in all setting there it is showing running

```
'/usr/sbin/userdel' failed: Child process exited with code 16.
```

now I've no idea how do I remove this unwanted user.

Comment: 'user sonu is currently used by process 13404'
Says all you need to know.

Comment: so you mean till process 13404 will be using user sonu i will not be able to remove it.

Comment: I guess, after rebooting you will be able to remove the user. Or you find the process with `htop`.

Comment: rebooting worked

Answer (score 3):

try

```
su - 
Password: <Enter password of root user> 
root@host: sudo deluser sonu
```

*sidenote :*
If you write `su-` for very first time on the terminal then first you have to activate *root* user by assigning password.

```
$ sudo passwd root
[sudo] password for <currentuser>:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

---

**tips:** keyword search of man pages can be then performed using **man -k keyword**

```
 man -k user  
 man -k password
```

will gives the list of useful commands with brief info

Comment: su - will not work in Ubuntu by default. Use sudo -i

Comment: @bodhi.zazen you website has no contact email.

Comment: @diEcho Leave a comment on most any blog page and I will send it to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with these commands in terminal:

```
sudo userdel user_name
sudo rm -rf /home/user_name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check for processes from the user using lsof -u username and kill the relevant PIDs.

Or pkill -u username or pkill -u uid

Comment: How does this help in removing a user?

Answer (score 1):

if none of the above method worked, install webmin and delete the user from GUI interface, it works 100%

1. sudo apt-get install webmin.
2. open internet browser and goto https://localhost:10000/
3. system > user and groups.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should list all the processes related to the particular user by using:

```
pgrep -u username
```

or

```
ps -f --pid $(pgrep -u username)
```

Then you can kill all processes running for that user by:

```
killall -9 -u username
```